# WP 3.3 update disabled editor stylesheet? Or TinyMCE Advanced problem?

Tags: visual-editor, plugin-tinymce

I have several CMS websites using TinyMCE Advanced plugin and the editor-style.css style sheet to make editor text resemble website text. After updating to WP 3.3, the editor no longer uses the stylesheet on any of the sites.

This might not be a WP 3.3 problem: once I updated WP, TinyMCE Advanced showed that it needed to be updated, so updated that. The problem could very well be with the latest version of TinyMCE Advanced.

Any clues about why or how to fix?

Although I still don't know if the problem is with WP 3.3 or TinyMCE Advanced (I suspect the latter), the following function in my functions.php file enables the editor stylesheet:

```
// Add custom stylesheet to TinyMCE editor
if ( ! function_exists('tdav_css') ) {
    function tdav_css($wp) {
    $wp .= ',' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/editor-style.css';
        return $wp;
    }
}
add_filter( 'mce_css', 'tdav_css' );
```

Problem solved.

Comment: Try disabling the plugin once and see if you get the expected behavior. If yes, then the plugin is doing it else WordPress, if only these two have changed since the last time they were working.

Comment: Good thought, but I'm not sure it's that simple, since TinyMCE Advanced is what enables the stylesheet when placed in the theme folder. So of course, with the plugin activated, the stylesheet also does not style the editor content.

Comment: Guess I will add a function in my functions file to enable the editor stylesheet.

Comment: `add_editor_style()`, combined with `editor-style.css`, is your friend here. :) While I'm sure there are other, valid reasons for using TinyMCE Advanced Plugin, styling the editor to match the front end is **not** one of them. WordPress core handles it by default (though it must be supported on a per-Theme basis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :
Step 1 : Change the theme
Step 2 : Clear the cache
Step 3 : Go to your editor 
Step 4 : Change to 'HTML'
Step 5 : Change to " Visual Editor'
Step 6 : Now you can find the Visual Editor Options
Step 7 : Change to your original theme

If Problem Persists, Add ' WP-Super Edit / Use Google Library ' Plugins, then check it. :)